# Node Callback Populating Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I'm new to node and have a question on callbacks. Given the following code:

```
function wrapperFunction(x) {

    var result = {};

    asyncWrapperFunction(x, function(res) {
        console.log(res); // successfully logs res
        result[x] = res; // populates result
    });

    return result; // returns result before fully populated

}

function asyncWrapperFunction(x, callback) {

    asyncFunction(x, function(err, res) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        return callback(res);
    });

}

wrapperFunction(5);
```

When calling `wrapperFunction(5)`, I'm able to log the result from within the `asyncWrapperFunction` call but `result` is returned before the request completes and of course is undefined. I know why this is happening.

The question is, what is the best practice to populate `result` in my example and only return it once they async function call(s) are complete?

Comment: there is no way, you cannot mix async and sync calls. you must handle all result logic sometime after the callback is hit.

Comment: best practice is to use promise objects http://blog.mediumequalsmessage.com/promise-deferred-objects-in-javascript-pt1-theory-and-semantics

Comment: Did I not say I was new to node? Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

given a need to use an async function from somewhere else, my preference is pure callbacks:

```
function asyncFunction(x, function(err, res) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    return callback(res);
  });
}

function invokerFunction(x) {
  var result = {};
  asyncFunction(x, function(res) {
    console.log(res); // successfully logs res
    result[x] = res; // populates result
    console.log(result);
    continueWithProgram(result);
  });
}
```

the promises suggested by @ChrisC would look more like:

```
invokerFunction(x)
.then(continueWithProgram)
```